# ld warning: stack subl instruction is too different from dwarf stack size on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, linker, clang, dwarf

recently we started getting this warning on our OS X build.

```
ld: warning:
could not create compact unwind for __Z10createMenuv: stack subl instruction is too different from dwarf stack size
ld: warning:
could not create compact unwind for __Z10del_modulejb: stack subl instruction is too different from dwarf stack size
could not create compact unwind for __Z14menu_patchbytev: stack subl instruction is too different from dwarf stack size
```

I could find some discussion of this in the Chromium bug tracker but the suggested "fix" is to disable compact unwind generation. I would like to understand why this warning happens and if it's an issue in our code or in the toolchain.

Our toolchain is from Xcode 7.3.1:

```
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
```

Answer (score 3):

**In doing some research, the best answer I see that there is an issue with the toolchain and not your code specifically.**

It is building as 32 bit instead of 64 bit. And to solve this you need to do one of two things:

1. Use a 64 bit version of the xCode toolchain instead of the 32 bit
   one.
2. Provide the proper option during compilation in order to emit x86_64
   code

That is why some recommend unwinding but I don't see any option to suppress the warning about compact unwind. There seems to be only an option to enable the warning `-warn_compact_unwind`.

What you could do is to suppress all linker warnings passing -Wl,-w option to compiler.

Another temporary solution you could try is passing `-Wl,-no_compact_unwind` to clang. It should instruct the linker not to generate compact unwind information.

Lastly, try compiling for 64 bit architecture. To do so you specify the architecture with `-arch` compiler option – in your case `-arch x86_64`.
.

I see most users pointing to Xcode 7 and at times Xcode 6 being the problem builds.

**In addition, there is one other method to fix this.**

> In project Build Settings find Build Options and set No in option
>   Enable Bitcode. I hope that it help for you.

Comment: we're not using Xcode IDE but compiling from commandline using `make` and the `gcc` driver.

Comment: also, we have this warning for x86 (`-arch i386`) builds, not x64 (`-arch x86_64`) ones.